# How to implement Pipe on combineLatest - angular15

Tags: typescript, angular15

How can I implement Pipe & map to get the data from both service and return to Observable. Below is the code which I need to modify to use Pipe instead of subscribe to send to oservable(data$?). Any help on how I can achieve or any other approach to do this. I need to pass to data$? thats is the goal.

```
data$?: Observable<any| undefined>;

 loadData(): void {
this.data$? = this.subscriptions.add(
  combineLatest([
    this.manageEmployeesService.employeeSummarySubject,
    this.currentEmployeeService.employeeSummarySubject
  ]).subscribe({
    next: (data: [EmployeeSummaryDto[], EmployeeSummaryDto]) => {
      this.currentEmployee = data[1];
      this.employees = data[0].filter(
        (i) => i.siteGuid == this.currentEmployee?.siteGuid
      );
      this.departmentList = this.manageEmployeesService
        .get('departments')
        .filter(
          (i) => i.siteGuid == this.currentEmployee?.siteGuid
        );
      const container = {
      schema: this.customColumnSchema,
      items: response
    };
    return container;
    }
  })
);
```

}